# Navigation Drawer not showing main fragment

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer

I just copied the Navigation Drawer example from developer.android.com. The Drawer works and I can change Activity with it but the problem is that I can't see the fragment of my activity. What is my problem?
Here's my code:

Activity.java:

```
public class Guide extends ActionBarActivity {

private String[] drawerListViewItems;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView drawerListView;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

boolean isPlayersOpen = false;
boolean isMatchOpen = false;
boolean isTournamentOpen = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guide);

    // get list items from strings.xml
    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.activity_list);
    // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

    // 2. App Icon 
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // 2.1 create ActionBarDrawerToggle
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
            );

    // 2.2 Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    // 2.3 enable and show "up" arrow
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 

    // just styling option
    drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.guide, menu);
    return true;
}

public void extendPlayer(View view){

    ImageView extendPlayer = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.players1);
    ImageView collapsePlayer = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.players2);
    TextView players_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.players_guide_text);

    if(isPlayersOpen){

        extendPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        collapsePlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        players_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        isPlayersOpen = false;

    } else {

        extendPlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        collapsePlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        players_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isPlayersOpen = true;

    }

}

public void extendMatch(View view){

    ImageView extendMatch = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.match1);
    ImageView collapseMatch = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.match2);
    TextView match_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.match_guide_text);

    if(isMatchOpen){

        extendMatch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        collapseMatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        match_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        isMatchOpen = false;

    } else {

        extendMatch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        collapseMatch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        match_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isMatchOpen = true;

    }

}

public void extendTournament(View view){

    ImageView extendTournament = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tournament1);
    ImageView collapseTournament = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tournament2);
    TextView tournament_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tournament_guide_text);

    if(isTournamentOpen){

        extendTournament.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        collapseTournament.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tournament_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        isTournamentOpen = false;

    } else {

        extendTournament.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        collapseTournament.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tournament_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        isTournamentOpen = true;

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
      return true;
    }
    // Handle your other action bar items...

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);

        if(position == 0){

            Intent intent = new Intent(Guide.this, Players.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        if(position == 1){

            Toast.makeText(Guide.this, ((TextView)view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        if(position == 2){

            Intent intent = new Intent(Guide.this, Tournaments.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        if(position == 3){



        }

        if(position == 4){

            Intent intent = new Intent(Guide.this, Info.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_guide,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

ExtendPlayer, ExtendMatch and ExtendTournament are my personal methods.

Activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ddd"/>
```

and my Fragments is called fragment_guide.xml

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's preferable if you don't start new activities on selecting the NavigationDrawer List items. What you should do, is just replace the existing fragment in the `FrameLayout` with the id `contentframe`. This has the benefit that it'll make it easier for you to scale your application later to tablets.

Regarding your question about fragments not getting instantiated, you have nothing in your `FrameLayout` in your **Activity.xml**. You would want to instantiate your fragments inside this `FrameLayout`. And after selecting the option from the NavigationDrawer List, just replace the fragment in the `FrameLayout` with the corresponding fragments.

Use [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) to achieve this.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help! I do what you say so now the fragments change and it's all fine except that when I press a button in one fragments I recieve a NoSuchMethodException because the method is in the Activity and I only change the fragment. What do I have to do? Do I have to put all my methods in the MainActivity?

Comment: If you have a button in a fragment, and the method that you want to use corresponding to the button click is something that is specific to the fragment, then it makes sense to keep the method in the fragment.
 I would suggest you go through the developer pages for [fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) once again. Also, this [vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html) can also be helpful.